# Create HTML template > translate > publish variables to template (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to create an HTML template using HTMLService, translate the template content, then publish variables to the template, before sending an email with the content.

It is important the variables are published after the template is translated (the variables will be content provided by the user so do not need them translated).

I am struggling to add variables to the template after it has been translated.

**HTML template** (test.html)

```
<table><tr><td>
 Text (in english) which needs to be translated.<br><br> 
 <?=variable?>
</td></tr></table>
```

**GAS code**

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').getRawContent();
var translatedmessage = LanguageApp.translate(template, 'en', 'es', {contentType: 'html'});
translatedmessage.variable = "service";

// I have a number of variables and do not want them translated.

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: 'email address',
  subject: 'This subject',
  htmlBody: translatedmessage
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s best to completely separate the business logic layer (text + translation) from building a view (pushing text to the template and adding variables). In .gs code, declare your text as a global variable or object property.

```
var data = { text: “your text };
```

Next, define the text translation function:

```
function translate (text) {

  return LanguageApp.translate(text, sourceLang, targetLang);

  }
```

In your template, add containers to house the text returned by the translate function and other variables , e.g.

```
<div><?!= translation ></div>
<div><?!= variable ></div>
```

Finally, create your template from file, set your variables and run the evaluate() method to convert to HtmlOutput.

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test');
var translatedmessage =   translate(data.text);
template.translation = translatedmessage;
template.variable = "service";

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: 'email address',
  subject: 'This subject',
  htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()
})
```

Comment: Thanks Anton. I was hoping there would be an easier way by translating the whole HTML template first, rather than translating the content individually. But that's ok this is the way I have another project set up and still works.

Comment: I don't think it's easier. For example, this line translatedmessage.variable = "service" will not work in JavaScript, because your variable is of String type, not of HtmlTemplate type. The return type  for HtmlService.getRawContent() is 'String' - when you execute this method against your template, you can no longer set variables for scriptlets enclosed between <? ?>

Comment: The reason why I wanted to translate the template was because I have already built templates with a large amount of content, so rather than pulling out all the content as individual variables, then translating the variables, I thought it would be easier to translate the template then add the user specific variables later. Does that makes sense? Nevertheless, I have converted the template to containers / variables overnight so I can translate only the variables I need translated. Thanks very much for your help Anton.